# Dynamic height based on viewport height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which resizes the height of a targeted element
but it only works with resize event, not when the page is loaded.
What could be the flaw here that doesn't set the height dynamically with the page load?

I'd also like to know how I can make the iterated codes into a modular structure in
this scenario.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
    var search = $(#something).outerHeight();
    $(".k-grid-content").height(viewportHeight - (400 - search));
});

$(function () {
    var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
    var search = $("#something").outerHeight();
    $(".k-grid-content").height(viewportHeight - (400 - search));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
var resizeGrid = function() {
    var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
    var search = $("#something").outerHeight();
    $(".k-grid-content").height(viewportHeight - (400 - search));
};
$(window).resize(function() {
    resizeGrid();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).trigger("resize");
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I like this structure. Unfortunately, dynamic height on first page load still doesn't work but I think it's something to do with the framework I'm working with. It's hard to replicate it here so I got what I needed!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.ready`:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
       var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
       var search = $("#something").outerHeight();
       $(".k-grid-content").height(viewportHeight - (400 - search));
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this in case it would make a difference but unfortunately this did not resolve the issue. Thanks for your input though.